# Return the result of an aggregate as an object not an array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have models in my collection this way..

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f213786d0cdd10c61969fc7"
    },
    "stationStatus": "Online",
    "metadata": {
        "SerialNumber": "BP001",
        "imsi": "082943327103528941"
    },
    "boxIdentity": "BP001",
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f213786d0cdd10c61969fc7"
    },
    "stationStatus": "Offline",
    "metadata": {
        "SerialNumber": "BP002",
        "imsi": "082943327103528941"
    },
    "boxIdentity": "BP002",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is the aggregation i'm performing on the data.

```
       var aggregation = [
        {
          $project: { __v: false },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { $toLower: "$stationStatus" },
            stations: {
              $push: "$$ROOT",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            stations: {
              $push: {
                k: "$_id",
                v: "$stations",
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$stations" },
          },
        },
      ];
      Model.aggregate(aggregation)
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject(err);
        });
```

Data I'm receiving in an array. What I need it the data to return only the result of the pipeline in the object, not the object inside the topmost array. How can I return the result in a way so that only the first object of the array is returned, as all that the aggregation is going to return is only a single object.

```
 [
        {
            "online": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f213786d0cdd10c61969fc7",
                    "stationStatus": "Online",
                    "connectors": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f213786d0cdd10c61969fc8",
                           ...
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f213791d0cdd10c61969fcf",
                            ...
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f213791d0cdd10c61969fd1",
                            ...
                        }
                    ],
                    "metadata": {
                        "SerialNumber": "BP001",
                        "imsi": "082943327103528941"
                    },
                    "boxIdentity": "BP001"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f2809d7b03827069d3b5627",
                    "stationStatus": "Online",
                    "connectors": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f213786d0ccc310c61969fc8",
                           ...
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f213791d0cd340c61969fcf",
                            ...
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f213791d0cdd10c61369fd1",
                            ...
                        }
                    ],
                    "metadata": {
                        "SerialNumber": "BP002",
                        "imsi": "0963433223503528941"
                    },
                    "boxIdentity": "BP002"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate will always return an array.

You could destructure the value if your using es6.

```
Model.aggregate(aggregation)
  .then(function ([theObjectYouWant]) {
    console.log(theObjectYouWant);
    ....
```

Comment: I'm using ES6. How do I destructure to get the first element?

Comment: Look at the snippet in my answer closer, The callback is destructuing the result to get ```theObjectYouWant```